# Difficulty converting query results to an array to apply ng-repeat and search filter

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I have been attempting various solutions I have read before on SO and I seem to not be able to resolve my issue. I am a newbie to the ANgular-Ionic framework as well as I am using Parse.com as my backend. So here is my problem:

In my Parse database I have a list of categories.
When retrieving the list of categories from Parse Query into my app, I cannot convert the results correctly to apply ng-repeat in the view in such a way that I can easily apply a filter to Search from an input box on the view. I am applying the query in a controller, (I know a service will have been nicer but taking one step at a time). Here is the code below

```
<ion-view view-title="Categories">

 <ion-content>
   <div class="col-md-2">
   <!--Sidebar content-->

   Search: <input ng-model="query" placeholder="Search for category">

   </div>
   <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="category in categories |filter:query" href="#/app/categories/{{category.id}}">
    <!--div ng-repeat="(key,value) in category">{{key}} {{value}}</div-->
     <img ng-src="assets\img\categories\{{category.name}}.jpg" >
       {{category.name}}
      </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And here is the controller applied to the view

```
.controller('AppController', function($scope){

$scope.categories = [];

function getCategories(){

    var items = [];
    var category = [];
    var BusinessCategory = Parse.Object.extend("BusinessCategory");
    var query = new Parse.Query(BusinessCategory);
    //query.select("objectId", "name","frequency");
    query.find().then(function(results){
        for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++){
            category.name = results[i].get("name");
            category.id = results[i].id;
            category.frequency = results[i].get("frequency");
            console.log(category.name+" "+category.id);
            items.push(category);
            category = [];
        }
        $scope.categories = items;
        $scope.items = items;

    });
}

getCategories();
}
```

The console.log printout is successful which tells me that I am successfully converting the results object into a category array which then is pushed 
into the scopes items and categories properties. But the view is not rendering any categories so I am a bit lost as to why it is not rendering the categories. Help truly appreciated.

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgAlY.png)

Comment: I'd suggest to add a plunkr to replicate the issue.

Comment: Done at http://plnkr.co/edit/f8jb06XIMIbp2UZPKpAM?p=streamer @ Diana R

Comment: Looks like your plunkr is not even compiling angular - `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`, do you have the same error in browser console when running your application?

Comment: Sorry I am not certain if my dependencies are off and therefore its not rendering. Please feel free to join me there. I will greatly appreciate. @ Diana R I do not get this error in my project.

Comment: New Plunkr same problem with dependencies. http://plnkr.co/edit/Mv0ta5VoWgDZoPo5mQjF?p=gitter

Comment: @ Diane I corrected the rendering problem however my ng-model search text is not binding to the ng-repeat list. My only guess is that the scope categories are not rendered as text in the view. I added a screenshot to show the search bar. I am hoping to implement an ionic filter bar in the header after but i think this step is an important first step to ensure that I am rendering the list category correctly

Comment: change your ng-repeat to be `ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:query" `

Comment: Sorry I did that in my original code but excluded it while debugging. It still does not work. I will have to write a custom filter however, the {{category.name}} should work on the query filter. Not sure why its not binding

Comment: Well you will have to fix plunkr to replicate your mist recent issue if you want if fixed here.

Comment: I corrected the issue but I will use plunkr in the future to trouble shoot problems. I have set up the environment on plunkr to allow my code to work. Thanks for the inadvertent recommendation however as I believe it will help me solve issue faster going forward.